# update look up with old value on update

Tags: apex, trigger, update

i have a parent__C field and i am trying to capture its prior value when it is updated. Not the value it was updated from but the value prior to the update i have a trigger i think should be working but the field wont populate

Am i missing some thing

```
    trigger updateid on Forecast__c (before update) {

  for (Forecast__c foe : Trigger.new) {


      IF(Trigger.oldMap.get(foe.parent__r.Id) != NULL){


      forecast__c oldfoe = Trigger.oldMap.get(foe.parent__r.Id);

          if (oldfoe != NULL) {

      foe.oldidlook__c = oldfoe.id;
    }
  }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the immediate fields of `Forecast__c` will have values in your trigger: the relationship fields (that end in `__r`) will be null. However the Id values that the relationships are based on will be populated.

If you want to check if the parent object has changed and save the value before the change, you can do that via the `parent__c` field that (I assume) holds the Id of the parent:

```
trigger updateid on Forecast__c (before update) {
    for (Forecast__c f : Trigger.new) {
        Forecast__c old = Trigger.oldMap.get(f.Id);
        if (f.parent__c != old.parent__c) f.oldidlook__c = old.parent__c;
    }
}
```